# Invalid format exception parsing string to JodaTime

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, jodatime

my version of JodaTime is 2.2. 
I have code:

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HHmmss");
DateTime dt = df.parseDateTime(time);
```

which throws error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "060000" is malformed 
      at "" 
      at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:871)
```

Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure *that exact code* fails for you? It works for me.

Comment: It fails for me on the tomcat server, I'll investigate more

Comment: `at ""` <-- that is strange... Isn't there a nul character before the date itself? Try and print the first character of the input string

Comment: I debugged and it had 3 extra chars at the end of the time parameter. Thank you for helping me - I could not see it in exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are blank control characters in your time variable, otherwise this should work.

Try replacing "time" with "060000" as a string literal and see what happens